# How do I tell Visual Studio to include a library's .cpp file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am using `lodepng` to produce compressed image files. I have stored the `.cpp` and `.h` files (there is only 1 of each) in `C:/Program Files/Common Files/lodepng/lodepng`, and I want my visual studio project to automatically look in these folders.

I have added `C:/Program Files/Common Files/lodepng` to my `Include Directories`, so wherever I have `#include <lodepng/lodepng.h>` it not picks up that header file, which is nice.

However, when I try to compile I get a linker error (obviously) because I haven't told VS where to look for the `.cpp` file (it's in `C:/Program Files/Common Files/lodepng/lodepng/lodepng.cpp`). But how do I tell it that?

Currently the fix I'm using is to simply drag and drop `loadpng.cpp` into my `Source Files` of the project, but this isn't a very nice solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think there is an automatic way to pick up all the .cpp files from a directory and include them in `Source Files`. I would love to be wrong on this :) :)

Comment: Generally, a pre built library would be provided and added as a linker dependency, in which case you don't need the implementation file.

Comment: One option is to #include the loadpng.cpp inside one of the other cpp files in your project. But as Chad points out you really should only be linking to a loadpng library.

Comment: Some users seem to be happy using CMake to generate `.vcproj` files. If, big if, CMake allows you to pick up all the files in a directory, that might be an options. Disclaimer: I have not used CMake myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your .cpp files to (compile with) your project.

Right click the project in the solution explorer, then select Add -> existing item and select your .cpp files. Note the folder the files live must be inlcuded to your diretories

Answer (score 1):

VC++ would only look files for you when encountering directives like:

```
#include "lodepng.h"
```

Though possible it is not a common practice to include a cpp file, in fact you could include text file for example to include very large data file etc.

Best practice is to add cpp file into your project, don't put any cpp file in a header folder and don't include them unless there are no any alternatives.